# Sum iteration using r

Tags: r, for-loop, sum, iteration, rolling-computation

I have a scoring matrix called `argRcount`.  The data is in form of a matrix where rownames indicate nucleotide names `a/t/c/g` and there are k = 18 columns indicating 1 to kth value of each of the nucleotide.

I have another data (list actually) where first item contains gene-names and second item contains a vector (character) of nucleotide sequence of say `n` characters.  In the below example n=450.

What I actually want is to have a rolling sum for each gene, wherein first `k` consecutive nucleotide sequence will matched from matrix `argRcount`, thereafter from 2nd nucleotide to 19th, and so on for each gene.  Thus in the end I will have `n-k+1` values (rolling sum values) for each gene.  In this particular example final outcome should have 433 values for each gene.

These are the dput of my data:

```
argRcount <- structure(c(0.149531733970964, 0.0317486983145803, -0.661398482245365, 
0.25489224962879, 0.517256514096281, -0.438254930931155, -0.949080554697146, 
0.25489224962879, 1.04334960999306, -1.35454566280531, -1.35454566280531, 
-0.438254930931155, 0.25489224962879, -0.101782694309942, 0.149531733970964, 
-0.438254930931155, -0.438254930931155, -0.949080554697146, -0.949080554697146, 
0.948039430188735, -0.949080554697146, -0.661398482245365, 1.04334960999306, 
-1.35454566280531, 1.04334960999306, -0.661398482245365, -0.949080554697146, 
-1.35454566280531, 1.04334960999306, -0.661398482245365, -0.949080554697146, 
-1.35454566280531, -0.661398482245365, -1.35454566280531, -2.04769284336526, 
1.13036098698269, 0.350202429433115, -2.04769284336526, -1.35454566280531, 
0.78552050069096, 0.149531733970964, -0.949080554697146, -2.04769284336526, 
0.842678914530909, -0.255933374137201, -2.04769284336526, -1.35454566280531, 
1.04334960999306, 0.0317486983145803, 0.0317486983145803, -2.04769284336526, 
0.591364486250003, 1.21040369465623, -2.04769284336526, -1.35454566280531, 
-1.35454566280531, -0.438254930931155, -0.661398482245365, -2.04769284336526, 
0.996829594358167, -0.949080554697146, -0.661398482245365, 0.724895878874526, 
0.0317486983145803, -0.949080554697146, 1.17118298150295, -2.04769284336526, 
-1.35454566280531, 1.21040369465623, -2.04769284336526, -0.949080554697146, 
-2.04769284336526), .Dim = c(4L, 18L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", 
"c", "g", "t"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18")))


upstream <- structure(list(gene_id = c("16127995", "16127996", "16127997", 
"16127998", "16127999"), seq = c("aacggcagaccaacatcaactgcaagctttacgcgaacgagccatgacattgctgacgactctggcagtggcagatgacataaaactggtcgactggttacaacaacgcctggggcttttagagcaacgagacacggcaatgttgcaccgtttgctgcatgatattgaaaaaaatatcaccaaataaaaaacgccttagtaagtatttttcagcttttcattctgactgcaacgggcaatatgtctctgtgtggattaaaaaaagagtgtctgatagcagcttctgaactggttacctgccgtgagtaaattaaaattttattgacttaggtcactaaatactttaaccaatataggcatagcgcacagacagataaaaattacagagtacacaacatccatgaaacgcattagcaccaccattaccaccaccatcaccattaccacagg", 
"ccgtttgctgcatgatattgaaaaaaatatcaccaaataaaaaacgccttagtaagtatttttcagcttttcattctgactgcaacgggcaatatgtctctgtgtggattaaaaaaagagtgtctgatagcagcttctgaactggttacctgccgtgagtaaattaaaattttattgacttaggtcactaaatactttaaccaatataggcatagcgcacagacagataaaaattacagagtacacaacatccatgaaacgcattagcaccaccattaccaccaccatcaccattaccacaggtaacggtgcgggctgacgcgtacaggaaacacagaaaaaagcccgcacctgacagtgcgggctttttttttcgaccaaaggtaacgaggtaacaaccatgcgagtgttgaagttcggcggtacatcagtggcaaatgcagaacgttt", 
"gaaacgggacgtgaactggagctggcggatattgaaattgaacctgtgctgcccgcagagtttaacgccgagggtgatgttgccgcttttatggcgaatctgtcacaactcgacgatctctttgccgcgcgcgtggcgaaggcccgtgatgaaggaaaagttttgcgctatgttggcaatattgatgaagatggcgtctgccgcgtgaagattgccgaagtggatggtaatgatccgctgttcaaagtgaaaaatggcgaaaacgccctggccttctatagccactattatcagccgctgccgttggtactgcgcggatatggtgcgggcaatgacgttacagctgccggtgtctttgctgatctgctacgtaccctctcatggaagttaggagtctgacatggttaaagtttatgccccggcttccagtgccaatatgagcgtcgggtt", 
"ggggattaaagtctcgacggcagaagccagggctattttaccggcgcagtatcgccgccaggattgcattgcgcacgggcgacatctggcaggcttcattcacgcctgctattcccgtcagcctgagcttgccgcgaagctgatgaaagatgttatcgctgaaccctaccgtgaacggttactgccaggcttccggcaggcgcggcaggcggtcgcggaaatcggcgcggtagcgagcggtatctccggctccggcccgaccttgttcgctctgtgtgacaagccggaaaccgcccagcgcgttgccgactggttgggtaagaactacctgcaaaatcaggaaggttttgttcatatttgccggctggatacggcgggcgcacgagtactggaaaactaaatgaaactctacaatctgaaagatcacaacgagcaggtcagctttgcgca", 
"aggcgaatatggcttgttcctcggcaccgcgcatccggcgaaatttaaagagagcgtggaagcgattctcggtgaaacgttggatctgccaaaagagctggcagaacgtgctgatttacccttgctttcacataatctgcccgccgattttgctgcgttgcgtaaattgatgatgaatcatcagtaaaatctattcattatctcaatcaggccgggtttgcttttatgcagcccggcttttttatgaagaaattatggagaaaaatgacagggaaaaaggagaaattctcaataaatgcggtaacttagagattaggattgcggagaataacaaccgccgttctcatcgagtaatctccggatatcgacccataacgggcaatgataaaaggagtaacctgtgaaaaagatgcaatctatcgtactcgcactttccctggttctggtcgc"
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

To have  a clear view my `argRcount` looks like this

```
           1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10         11
a  0.1495317  0.5172565  1.0433496  0.2548922 -0.4382549 -0.9490806  1.0433496  1.0433496 -0.6613985  0.3502024  0.1495317
c  0.0317487 -0.4382549 -1.3545457 -0.1017827 -0.9490806 -0.6613985 -0.6613985 -0.6613985 -1.3545457 -2.0476928 -0.9490806
g -0.6613985 -0.9490806 -1.3545457  0.1495317 -0.9490806  1.0433496 -0.9490806 -0.9490806 -2.0476928 -1.3545457 -2.0476928
t  0.2548922  0.2548922 -0.4382549 -0.4382549  0.9480394 -1.3545457 -1.3545457 -1.3545457  1.1303610  0.7855205  0.8426789
          12         13        14         15         16         17         18
a -0.2559334  0.0317487  1.210404 -0.4382549 -0.9490806 -0.9490806  1.2104037
c -2.0476928  0.0317487 -2.047693 -0.6613985 -0.6613985  1.1711830 -2.0476928
g -1.3545457 -2.0476928 -1.354546 -2.0476928  0.7248959 -2.0476928 -0.9490806
t  1.0433496  0.5913645 -1.354546  0.9968296  0.0317487 -1.3545457 -2.0476928
```

A sample sequence from upstream looks like this

```
> upstream[[2]][1]
[1] "aacggcagaccaacatcaactgcaagctttacgcgaacgagccatgacattgctgacgactctggcagtggcagatgacataaaactggtcgactggttacaacaacgcctggggcttttagagcaacgagacacggcaatgttgcaccgtttgctgcatgatattgaaaaaaatatcaccaaataaaaaacgccttagtaagtatttttcagcttttcattctgactgcaacgggcaatatgtctctgtgtggattaaaaaaagagtgtctgatagcagcttctgaactggttacctgccgtgagtaaattaaaattttattgacttaggtcactaaatactttaaccaatataggcatagcgcacagacagataaaaattacagagtacacaacatccatgaaacgcattagcaccaccattaccaccaccatcaccattaccacagg"
```

So far, I have tried this:

```
seq_score<-vector()
for (i in 1:length(upstream$seq)){
  seq_score[i]<-argRcount[upstream[[1]][i],i]
}

sum(seq_score)
sum(apply(argRcount,2,max))
```

But it only gives me the first 18 nucleotides score. Thanks in advance.

Comment: nucleotides are made up of these four letters: ACGT. I have made changes on the dput of my upstream df.

Comment: this would be 0.1495+0.5172-1.3545+0.1495-0.9491....for the first 5 bases. I want to sum up the score for 18 nucleotides (1st to 18th, 2nd to 19th and so on until 450th bases).

Comment: Ok.  Got it.  It is summing for first 18 because for loop `argRcount[upstream[[1]][i],i]` fails after i >18 as there are only 18 columns in argRcount.  Conside pacakge `zoo` or `runner` for this rolling computation.  Else consider nested loops.

Comment: Do you mind sharing a little bit more about the nested loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some packages:

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

k <- ncol(argRcount)

setNames(upstream[[2]], upstream[[1]]) %>%
  map(~match(str_split(.x, "")[[1]], rownames(argRcount))) %>%
  map(function(vec) map(seq_len(length(vec) - k + 1), ~vec[.x:(.x + k - 1)])) %>%
  map(function(gene_seq) map_dbl(gene_seq, ~sum(argRcount[matrix(c(.x, seq_len(k)), ncol = 2)])))
```

Comment: Excellent Strategy.  upvoted already.  Could you please spare a few moments to explain the logic especially in the second `map`

Comment: I understood the question wrong, I updated the answer (it's more complicated now that it used to be). Second `map` from vector creates multiple vectors, ex. from (1,2,...,20) it creates (1,...18), (2,...,19) and (3,...,20).

Comment: That's because `length(vec) + 1 < k`. Is this something that can happen (meaning that there is sequence of genes that is shorter than number of columns in argRcount)?

Answer (score 2):

**In view of changed data in upstream** BaseR strategy (without loading any extra pacakage/library)

```
#create an empty list for output
seq_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(upstream[[2]]))

#name it according to genes
seq_list <- setNames(seq_list, upstream[[1]])

#create an empty vector for storing intermediate objects
seq_score<-vector()

#modify upstream to split the nucleotides
upstream <- sapply(upstream[[2]], function(x) strsplit(x, ""))

#actual for loop
for(k in seq_along(upstream)){
  for(i in seq_len(length(upstream[[k]]) -17)){
    for(j in 1:18){
      seq_score[j] <- argRcount[upstream[[k]][i + j -1], j]
      seq_list[[k]][i] <- sum(seq_score)
    }
  }
}

#output
seq_list

#check it
str(seq_list)

List of 5
 $ 16127995: num [1:433] -6.01 -4.97 -10.22 -11.17 -4.3 ...
 $ 16127996: num [1:433] -9.81 -8.91 -10.75 -3.88 3.06 ...
 $ 16127997: num [1:433] -8.6 -3.81 -4.76 -9.88 -16.98 ...
 $ 16127998: num [1:433] -10.49 -8.48 -5.51 -9.31 -7.3 ...
 $ 16127999: num [1:433] -10.75 -15.01 -8.22 -8.08 -9.8 ...
```

**old answer**

For your earlier dput of `upstream` I have tried this nested `for loop`.  getting your desired out in `seq_list`.

```
#create an empty list for final output
seq_list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(upstream))

#create an empty vector for intermediate results
seq_score<- vector()

#for loop

for(k in seq_along(upstream)){
  for(i in seq_len(length(upstream[[k]]) -17)){
    for(j in 1:18){
      seq_score[j] <- argRcount[upstream[[k]][i + j -1], j]
      seq_list[[k]][i] <- sum(seq_score)
    }
  }
}

str(seq_list)

List of 10
 $ : num [1:433] -6.01 -4.97 -10.22 -11.17 -4.3 ...
 $ : num [1:433] -9.81 -8.91 -10.75 -3.88 3.06 ...
 $ : num [1:433] -8.6 -3.81 -4.76 -9.88 -16.98 ...
 $ : num [1:433] -10.49 -8.48 -5.51 -9.31 -7.3 ...
 $ : num [1:433] -10.75 -15.01 -8.22 -8.08 -9.8 ...
 $ : num [1:433] -9.69 -9.49 -4.56 -7.93 -10.06 ...
 $ : num [1:433] -7.95 -9.12 -12.18 -7.26 -9.62 ...
 $ : num [1:433] -10.22 -3.94 -10.88 -4.6 -7.54 ...
 $ : num [1:433] -8.57 -10.67 -9.04 -8.94 -12.3 ...
 $ : num [1:433] 0.0425 -3.5291 -9.2187 -6.5724 2.3064 ...
```

dput of earlier `upstream` used

```
upstream <- list(c("a", "a", "c", "g", "g", "c", "a", "g", "a", "c", "c", 
"a", "a", "c", "a", "t", "c", "a", "a", "c", "t", "g", "c", "a", 
"a", "g", "c", "t", "t", "t", "a", "c", "g", "c", "g", "a", "a", 
"c", "g", "a", "g", "c", "c", "a", "t", "g", "a", "c", "a", "t", 
"t", "g", "c", "t", "g", "a", "c", "g", "a", "c", "t", "c", "t", 
"g", "g", "c", "a", "g", "t", "g", "g", "c", "a", "g", "a", "t", 
"g", "a", "c", "a", "t", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "t", "g", "g", 
"t", "c", "g", "a", "c", "t", "g", "g", "t", "t", "a", "c", "a", 
"a", "c", "a", "a", "c", "g", "c", "c", "t", "g", "g", "g", "g", 
"c", "t", "t", "t", "t", "a", "g", "a", "g", "c", "a", "a", "c", 
"g", "a", "g", "a", "c", "a", "c", "g", "g", "c", "a", "a", "t", 
"g", "t", "t", "g", "c", "a", "c", "c", "g", "t", "t", "t", "g", 
"c", "t", "g", "c", "a", "t", "g", "a", "t", "a", "t", "t", "g", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "a", "t", "c", "a", "c", 
"c", "a", "a", "a", "t", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "g", 
"c", "c", "t", "t", "a", "g", "t", "a", "a", "g", "t", "a", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "t", "c", "a", "g", "c", "t", "t", "t", "t", "c", 
"a", "t", "t", "c", "t", "g", "a", "c", "t", "g", "c", "a", "a", 
"c", "g", "g", "g", "c", "a", "a", "t", "a", "t", "g", "t", "c", 
"t", "c", "t", "g", "t", "g", "t", "g", "g", "a", "t", "t", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "a", "g", "t", "g", "t", "c", 
"t", "g", "a", "t", "a", "g", "c", "a", "g", "c", "t", "t", "c", 
"t", "g", "a", "a", "c", "t", "g", "g", "t", "t", "a", "c", "c", 
"t", "g", "c", "c", "g", "t", "g", "a", "g", "t", "a", "a", "a", 
"t", "t", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "t", "t", "a", "t", "t", 
"g", "a", "c", "t", "t", "a", "g", "g", "t", "c", "a", "c", "t", 
"a", "a", "a", "t", "a", "c", "t", "t", "t", "a", "a", "c", "c", 
"a", "a", "t", "a", "t", "a", "g", "g", "c", "a", "t", "a", "g", 
"c", "g", "c", "a", "c", "a", "g", "a", "c", "a", "g", "a", "t", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "a", "c", "a", "g", "a", "g", 
"t", "a", "c", "a", "c", "a", "a", "c", "a", "t", "c", "c", "a", 
"t", "g", "a", "a", "a", "c", "g", "c", "a", "t", "t", "a", "g", 
"c", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c", "c", "a", "t", "t", "a", "c", "c", 
"a", "c", "c", "a", "c", "c", "a", "t", "c", "a", "c", "c", "a", 
"t", "t", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c", "a", "g", "g"), c("c", "c", 
"g", "t", "t", "t", "g", "c", "t", "g", "c", "a", "t", "g", "a", 
"t", "a", "t", "t", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", 
"a", "t", "c", "a", "c", "c", "a", "a", "a", "t", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "c", "g", "c", "c", "t", "t", "a", "g", "t", "a", 
"a", "g", "t", "a", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "c", "a", "g", "c", 
"t", "t", "t", "t", "c", "a", "t", "t", "c", "t", "g", "a", "c", 
"t", "g", "c", "a", "a", "c", "g", "g", "g", "c", "a", "a", "t", 
"a", "t", "g", "t", "c", "t", "c", "t", "g", "t", "g", "t", "g", 
"g", "a", "t", "t", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "a", 
"g", "t", "g", "t", "c", "t", "g", "a", "t", "a", "g", "c", "a", 
"g", "c", "t", "t", "c", "t", "g", "a", "a", "c", "t", "g", "g", 
"t", "t", "a", "c", "c", "t", "g", "c", "c", "g", "t", "g", "a", 
"g", "t", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "a", "t", "t", "g", "a", "c", "t", "t", "a", "g", "g", 
"t", "c", "a", "c", "t", "a", "a", "a", "t", "a", "c", "t", "t", 
"t", "a", "a", "c", "c", "a", "a", "t", "a", "t", "a", "g", "g", 
"c", "a", "t", "a", "g", "c", "g", "c", "a", "c", "a", "g", "a", 
"c", "a", "g", "a", "t", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "a", 
"c", "a", "g", "a", "g", "t", "a", "c", "a", "c", "a", "a", "c", 
"a", "t", "c", "c", "a", "t", "g", "a", "a", "a", "c", "g", "c", 
"a", "t", "t", "a", "g", "c", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c", "c", "a", 
"t", "t", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c", "c", "a", "t", 
"c", "a", "c", "c", "a", "t", "t", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c", "a", 
"g", "g", "t", "a", "a", "c", "g", "g", "t", "g", "c", "g", "g", 
"g", "c", "t", "g", "a", "c", "g", "c", "g", "t", "a", "c", "a", 
"g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "c", "a", "c", "a", "g", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "g", "c", "c", "c", "g", "c", "a", "c", "c", "t", 
"g", "a", "c", "a", "g", "t", "g", "c", "g", "g", "g", "c", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "c", "g", "a", "c", "c", 
"a", "a", "a", "g", "g", "t", "a", "a", "c", "g", "a", "g", "g", 
"t", "a", "a", "c", "a", "a", "c", "c", "a", "t", "g", "c", "g", 
"a", "g", "t", "g", "t", "t", "g", "a", "a", "g", "t", "t", "c", 
"g", "g", "c", "g", "g", "t", "a", "c", "a", "t", "c", "a", "g", 
"t", "g", "g", "c", "a", "a", "a", "t", "g", "c", "a", "g", "a", 
"a", "c", "g", "t", "t", "t"), c("g", "a", "a", "a", "c", "g", 
"g", "g", "a", "c", "g", "t", "g", "a", "a", "c", "t", "g", "g", 
"a", "g", "c", "t", "g", "g", "c", "g", "g", "a", "t", "a", "t", 
"t", "g", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "g", "a", "a", "c", "c", "t", 
"g", "t", "g", "c", "t", "g", "c", "c", "c", "g", "c", "a", "g", 
"a", "g", "t", "t", "t", "a", "a", "c", "g", "c", "c", "g", "a", 
"g", "g", "g", "t", "g", "a", "t", "g", "t", "t", "g", "c", "c", 
"g", "c", "t", "t", "t", "t", "a", "t", "g", "g", "c", "g", "a", 
"a", "t", "c", "t", "g", "t", "c", "a", "c", "a", "a", "c", "t", 
"c", "g", "a", "c", "g", "a", "t", "c", "t", "c", "t", "t", "t", 
"g", "c", "c", "g", "c", "g", "c", "g", "c", "g", "t", "g", "g", 
"c", "g", "a", "a", "g", "g", "c", "c", "c", "g", "t", "g", "a", 
"t", "g", "a", "a", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "g", "c", "g", "c", "t", "a", "t", "g", "t", "t", "g", 
"g", "c", "a", "a", "t", "a", "t", "t", "g", "a", "t", "g", "a", 
"a", "g", "a", "t", "g", "g", "c", "g", "t", "c", "t", "g", "c", 
"c", "g", "c", "g", "t", "g", "a", "a", "g", "a", "t", "t", "g", 
"c", "c", "g", "a", "a", "g", "t", "g", "g", "a", "t", "g", "g", 
"t", "a", "a", "t", "g", "a", "t", "c", "c", "g", "c", "t", "g", 
"t", "t", "c", "a", "a", "a", "g", "t", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "t", "g", "g", "c", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "g", "c", 
"c", "c", "t", "g", "g", "c", "c", "t", "t", "c", "t", "a", "t", 
"a", "g", "c", "c", "a", "c", "t", "a", "t", "t", "a", "t", "c", 
"a", "g", "c", "c", "g", "c", "t", "g", "c", "c", "g", "t", "t", 
"g", "g", "t", "a", "c", "t", "g", "c", "g", "c", "g", "g", "a", 
"t", "a", "t", "g", "g", "t", "g", "c", "g", "g", "g", "c", "a", 
"a", "t", "g", "a", "c", "g", "t", "t", "a", "c", "a", "g", "c", 
"t", "g", "c", "c", "g", "g", "t", "g", "t", "c", "t", "t", "t", 
"g", "c", "t", "g", "a", "t", "c", "t", "g", "c", "t", "a", "c", 
"g", "t", "a", "c", "c", "c", "t", "c", "t", "c", "a", "t", "g", 
"g", "a", "a", "g", "t", "t", "a", "g", "g", "a", "g", "t", "c", 
"t", "g", "a", "c", "a", "t", "g", "g", "t", "t", "a", "a", "a", 
"g", "t", "t", "t", "a", "t", "g", "c", "c", "c", "c", "g", "g", 
"c", "t", "t", "c", "c", "a", "g", "t", "g", "c", "c", "a", "a", 
"t", "a", "t", "g", "a", "g", "c", "g", "t", "c", "g", "g", "g", 
"t", "t"), c("g", "g", "g", "g", "a", "t", "t", "a", "a", "a", 
"g", "t", "c", "t", "c", "g", "a", "c", "g", "g", "c", "a", "g", 
"a", "a", "g", "c", "c", "a", "g", "g", "g", "c", "t", "a", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "a", "c", "c", "g", "g", "c", "g", "c", "a", "g", 
"t", "a", "t", "c", "g", "c", "c", "g", "c", "c", "a", "g", "g", 
"a", "t", "t", "g", "c", "a", "t", "t", "g", "c", "g", "c", "a", 
"c", "g", "g", "g", "c", "g", "a", "c", "a", "t", "c", "t", "g", 
"g", "c", "a", "g", "g", "c", "t", "t", "c", "a", "t", "t", "c", 
"a", "c", "g", "c", "c", "t", "g", "c", "t", "a", "t", "t", "c", 
"c", "c", "g", "t", "c", "a", "g", "c", "c", "t", "g", "a", "g", 
"c", "t", "t", "g", "c", "c", "g", "c", "g", "a", "a", "g", "c", 
"t", "g", "a", "t", "g", "a", "a", "a", "g", "a", "t", "g", "t", 
"t", "a", "t", "c", "g", "c", "t", "g", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", 
"t", "a", "c", "c", "g", "t", "g", "a", "a", "c", "g", "g", "t", 
"t", "a", "c", "t", "g", "c", "c", "a", "g", "g", "c", "t", "t", 
"c", "c", "g", "g", "c", "a", "g", "g", "c", "g", "c", "g", "g", 
"c", "a", "g", "g", "c", "g", "g", "t", "c", "g", "c", "g", "g", 
"a", "a", "a", "t", "c", "g", "g", "c", "g", "c", "g", "g", "t", 
"a", "g", "c", "g", "a", "g", "c", "g", "g", "t", "a", "t", "c", 
"t", "c", "c", "g", "g", "c", "t", "c", "c", "g", "g", "c", "c", 
"c", "g", "a", "c", "c", "t", "t", "g", "t", "t", "c", "g", "c", 
"t", "c", "t", "g", "t", "g", "t", "g", "a", "c", "a", "a", "g", 
"c", "c", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "g", "c", "c", "c", 
"a", "g", "c", "g", "c", "g", "t", "t", "g", "c", "c", "g", "a", 
"c", "t", "g", "g", "t", "t", "g", "g", "g", "t", "a", "a", "g", 
"a", "a", "c", "t", "a", "c", "c", "t", "g", "c", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "t", "c", "a", "g", "g", "a", "a", "g", "g", "t", "t", "t", 
"t", "g", "t", "t", "c", "a", "t", "a", "t", "t", "t", "g", "c", 
"c", "g", "g", "c", "t", "g", "g", "a", "t", "a", "c", "g", "g", 
"c", "g", "g", "g", "c", "g", "c", "a", "c", "g", "a", "g", "t", 
"a", "c", "t", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "t", "a", "a", 
"a", "t", "g", "a", "a", "a", "c", "t", "c", "t", "a", "c", "a", 
"a", "t", "c", "t", "g", "a", "a", "a", "g", "a", "t", "c", "a", 
"c", "a", "a", "c", "g", "a", "g", "c", "a", "g", "g", "t", "c", 
"a", "g", "c", "t", "t", "t", "g", "c", "g", "c", "a"), c("a", 
"g", "g", "c", "g", "a", "a", "t", "a", "t", "g", "g", "c", "t", 
"t", "g", "t", "t", "c", "c", "t", "c", "g", "g", "c", "a", "c", 
"c", "g", "c", "g", "c", "a", "t", "c", "c", "g", "g", "c", "g", 
"a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "t", "a", "a", "a", "g", "a", "g", "a", 
"g", "c", "g", "t", "g", "g", "a", "a", "g", "c", "g", "a", "t", 
"t", "c", "t", "c", "g", "g", "t", "g", "a", "a", "a", "c", "g", 
"t", "t", "g", "g", "a", "t", "c", "t", "g", "c", "c", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "g", "a", "g", "c", "t", "g", "g", "c", "a", "g", "a", 
"a", "c", "g", "t", "g", "c", "t", "g", "a", "t", "t", "t", "a", 
"c", "c", "c", "t", "t", "g", "c", "t", "t", "t", "c", "a", "c", 
"a", "t", "a", "a", "t", "c", "t", "g", "c", "c", "c", "g", "c", 
"c", "g", "a", "t", "t", "t", "t", "g", "c", "t", "g", "c", "g", 
"t", "t", "g", "c", "g", "t", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "g", "a", 
"t", "g", "a", "t", "g", "a", "a", "t", "c", "a", "t", "c", "a", 
"g", "t", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "c", "t", "a", "t", "t", "c", 
"a", "t", "t", "a", "t", "c", "t", "c", "a", "a", "t", "c", "a", 
"g", "g", "c", "c", "g", "g", "g", "t", "t", "t", "g", "c", "t", 
"t", "t", "t", "a", "t", "g", "c", "a", "g", "c", "c", "c", "g", 
"g", "c", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "a", "t", "g", "a", "a", 
"g", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "a", "t", "g", "g", "a", "g", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "g", "a", "c", "a", "g", "g", "g", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "g", "a", "g", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", 
"c", "t", "c", "a", "a", "t", "a", "a", "a", "t", "g", "c", "g", 
"g", "t", "a", "a", "c", "t", "t", "a", "g", "a", "g", "a", "t", 
"t", "a", "g", "g", "a", "t", "t", "g", "c", "g", "g", "a", "g", 
"a", "a", "t", "a", "a", "c", "a", "a", "c", "c", "g", "c", "c", 
"g", "t", "t", "c", "t", "c", "a", "t", "c", "g", "a", "g", "t", 
"a", "a", "t", "c", "t", "c", "c", "g", "g", "a", "t", "a", "t", 
"c", "g", "a", "c", "c", "c", "a", "t", "a", "a", "c", "g", "g", 
"g", "c", "a", "a", "t", "g", "a", "t", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", 
"g", "a", "g", "t", "a", "a", "c", "c", "t", "g", "t", "g", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "a", "t", "g", "c", "a", "a", "t", "c", 
"t", "a", "t", "c", "g", "t", "a", "c", "t", "c", "g", "c", "a", 
"c", "t", "t", "t", "c", "c", "c", "t", "g", "g", "t", "t", "c", 
"t", "g", "g", "t", "c", "g", "c"), c("c", "t", "a", "c", "a", 
"t", "t", "t", "a", "t", "g", "c", "c", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"c", "a", "a", "t", "c", "t", "c", "t", "t", "c", "t", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "a", "c", "g", "c", "c", "t", "g", "a", "a", "c", "a", 
"a", "c", "c", "c", "t", "a", "a", "a", "g", "c", "g", "a", "t", 
"c", "t", "g", "g", "t", "g", "t", "t", "t", "g", "c", "g", "g", 
"a", "t", "c", "t", "g", "c", "a", "c", "c", "t", "t", "c", "g", 
"c", "a", "a", "c", "g", "g", "t", "c", "a", "t", "c", "g", "g", 
"c", "g", "g", "c", "a", "c", "c", "t", "t", "g", "c", "t", "a", 
"a", "g", "c", "c", "t", "t", "c", "c", "g", "c", "t", "g", "a", 
"t", "g", "t", "g", "g", "c", "a", "a", "c", "t", "g", "g", "c", 
"a", "g", "a", "t", "a", "t", "c", "a", "t", "a", "a", "t", "g", 
"g", "c", "c", "t", "g", "c", "a", "t", "g", "g", "c", "t", "a", 
"t", "t", "a", "c", "c", "a", "a", "t", "t", "t", "g", "a", "c", 
"c", "g", "c", "c", "a", "t", "t", "t", "t", "a", "c", "t", "g", 
"c", "t", "c", "t", "c", "g", "c", "c", "t", "g", "t", "g", "g", 
"t", "t", "c", "a", "t", "a", "c", "c", "a", "t", "t", "g", "c", 
"c", "a", "g", "t", "g", "a", "t", "t", "a", "t", "c", "t", "a", 
"c", "g", "c", "c", "a", "g", "c", "g", "t", "a", "a", "a", "c", 
"t", "c", "g", "g", "c", "g", "t", "g", "c", "g", "c", "c", "c", 
"g", "g", "t", "g", "t", "t", "t", "g", "a", "t", "c", "c", "a", 
"t", "t", "g", "c", "g", "t", "t", "a", "t", "c", "c", "g", "g", 
"a", "t", "a", "t", "c", "g", "g", "t", "c", "g", "c", "c", "a", 
"g", "c", "t", "t", "t", "c", "t", "c", "c", "g", "g", "a", "c", 
"g", "c", "g", "t", "g", "g", "g", "a", "t", "g", "a", "t", "g", 
"t", "t", "t", "c", "g", "c", "a", "g", "g", "a", "g", "t", "a", 
"a", "t", "c", "a", "c", "a", "a", "c", "t", "a", "t", "c", "g", 
"a", "t", "c", "a", "a", "c", "t", "c", "a", "t", "t", "c", "t", 
"c", "a", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "g", "c", "t", "a", "a", 
"a", "g", "t", "c", "g", "g", "c", "a", "t", "a", "a", "a", "t", 
"t", "t", "c", "c", "t", "g", "c", "a", "a", "g", "g", "a", "c", 
"t", "g", "g", "a", "t", "a", "t", "g", "c", "t", "g", "a", "t", 
"t", "c", "t", "t", "a", "t", "t", "t", "c", "a", "c", "c", "t", 
"g", "c", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "g", "c", "t", "t", "g", 
"a", "t", "t", "a", "c", "c", "a", "a", "a", "g", "c", "c", "c", 
"g", "t", "t"), c("t", "t", "a", "a", "g", "a", "a", "t", "g", 
"a", "g", "a", "g", "a", "a", "g", "g", "g", "t", "t", "g", "g", 
"t", "t", "g", "t", "g", "g", "c", "a", "t", "c", "c", "t", "g", 
"c", "g", "g", "t", "t", "g", "a", "t", "a", "c", "a", "g", "c", 
"t", "t", "c", "a", "t", "t", "g", "c", "c", "g", "c", "g", "a", 
"t", "g", "t", "c", "c", "c", "c", "a", "g", "t", "g", "t", "c", 
"g", "g", "c", "c", "a", "c", "t", "a", "c", "g", "g", "t", "g", 
"g", "t", "g", "t", "a", "c", "t", "g", "a", "c", "g", "a", "a", 
"g", "g", "g", "a", "g", "g", "t", "c", "a", "a", "t", "t", "t", 
"g", "t", "c", "c", "g", "t", "c", "a", "t", "g", "a", "t", "a", 
"g", "t", "a", "t", "t", "t", "c", "t", "c", "t", "t", "t", "a", 
"a", "a", "c", "a", "g", "c", "t", "t", "g", "t", "t", "a", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "g", "a", "t", "g", "t", "a", "a", "c", "c", "g", 
"g", "t", "c", "t", "g", "c", "c", "c", "t", "g", "a", "t", "g", 
"a", "t", "a", "t", "c", "a", "c", "g", "a", "c", "g", "c", "a", 
"a", "c", "g", "t", "c", "a", "g", "c", "g", "c", "a", "a", "c", 
"c", "g", "c", "c", "g", "a", "c", "a", "a", "g", "a", "c", "g", 
"g", "t", "t", "a", "t", "c", "g", "c", "c", "a", "g", "g", "c", 
"g", "a", "g", "a", "c", "t", "g", "t", "t", "t", "c", "g", "g", 
"a", "t", "t", "t", "c", "t", "g", "a", "c", "a", "c", "t", "g", 
"c", "g", "t", "t", "g", "a", "t", "a", "t", "c", "g", "c", "c", 
"c", "g", "c", "c", "a", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "a", "t", "a", 
"c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "t", "c", "a", "t", "g", "t", 
"a", "t", "g", "c", "t", "a", "c", "g", "c", "a", "g", "a", "a", 
"g", "t", "t", "a", "t", "c", "a", "a", "g", "t", "a", "c", "c", 
"t", "c", "g", "t", "a", "g", "c", "g", "t", "a", "t", "a", "t", 
"a", "c", "t", "t", "c", "t", "t", "a", "a", "a", "c", "a", "a", 
"t", "t", "g", "g", "t", "a", "a", "c", "g", "t", "t", "t", "a", 
"c", "a", "c", "a", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "g", "t", "c", "a", 
"t", "c", "g", "c", "g", "a", "c", "c", "g", "g", "c", "a", "a", 
"t", "a", "a", "g", "a", "g", "g", "g", "a", "t", "a", "t", "g", 
"c", "a", "t", "g", "c", "c", "a", "g", "a", "t", "t", "t", "t", 
"t", "t", "c", "t", "c", "c", "t", "t", "c", "a", "t", "t", "a", 
"a", "c", "a", "g", "c", "g", "t", "c", "c", "t", "t", "t", "g", 
"g", "g", "g", "a", "t", "c", "g", "g", "t", "a", "a", "t"), 
    c("c", "g", "g", "a", "t", "g", "t", "a", "g", "c", "g", 
    "a", "a", "a", "c", "t", "g", "c", "a", "c", "a", "a", "a", 
    "t", "c", "c", "g", "g", "t", "g", "c", "g", "a", "a", "a", 
    "a", "g", "t", "g", "a", "a", "c", "c", "a", "a", "c", "a", 
    "a", "c", "c", "t", "g", "c", "g", "c", "c", "g", "a", "a", 
    "g", "a", "g", "c", "a", "g", "g", "t", "a", "a", "a", "t", 
    "c", "a", "t", "t", "a", "c", "c", "g", "a", "t", "c", "c", 
    "c", "c", "a", "a", "a", "g", "g", "a", "c", "g", "c", "t", 
    "g", "t", "t", "a", "a", "t", "g", "a", "a", "g", "g", "a", 
    "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "c", "t", "g", "g", 
    "c", "a", "t", "g", "c", "a", "t", "a", "t", "c", "c", "c", 
    "t", "c", "t", "t", "a", "t", "t", "g", "c", "c", "g", "g", 
    "t", "c", "g", "c", "g", "a", "t", "g", "a", "c", "t", "t", 
    "t", "c", "c", "t", "g", "t", "g", "t", "a", "a", "a", "c", 
    "g", "t", "t", "a", "c", "c", "a", "a", "t", "t", "g", "t", 
    "t", "t", "a", "a", "g", "a", "a", "g", "t", "a", "t", "a", 
    "t", "a", "c", "g", "c", "t", "a", "c", "g", "a", "g", "g", 
    "t", "a", "c", "t", "t", "g", "a", "t", "a", "a", "c", "t", 
    "t", "c", "t", "g", "c", "g", "t", "a", "g", "c", "a", "t", 
    "a", "c", "a", "t", "g", "a", "g", "g", "t", "t", "t", "t", 
    "g", "t", "a", "t", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "g", "g", 
    "c", "g", "g", "g", "c", "g", "a", "t", "a", "t", "c", "a", 
    "a", "c", "g", "c", "a", "g", "t", "g", "t", "c", "a", "g", 
    "a", "a", "a", "t", "c", "c", "g", "a", "a", "a", "c", "a", 
    "g", "t", "c", "t", "c", "g", "c", "c", "t", "g", "g", "c", 
    "g", "a", "t", "a", "a", "c", "c", "g", "t", "c", "t", "t", 
    "g", "t", "c", "g", "g", "c", "g", "g", "t", "t", "g", "c", 
    "g", "c", "t", "g", "a", "c", "g", "t", "t", "g", "c", "g", 
    "t", "c", "g", "t", "g", "a", "t", "a", "t", "c", "a", "t", 
    "c", "a", "g", "g", "g", "c", "a", "g", "a", "c", "c", "g", 
    "g", "t", "t", "a", "c", "a", "t", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
    "t", "a", "a", "c", "a", "a", "g", "c", "t", "g", "t", "t", 
    "t", "a", "a", "a", "g", "a", "g", "a", "a", "a", "t", "a", 
    "c", "t", "a", "t", "c", "a", "t", "g", "a", "c", "g", "g", 
    "a", "c", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "g", "a", "c", "c", "t", 
    "c", "c", "c", "t", "t", "c", "g", "t", "c", "a", "g", "t", 
    "a", "c", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c", "c", "g", "t", "a", "g", 
    "t", "g", "g", "c", "c", "g", "a"), c("g", "g", "g", "c", 
    "g", "c", "a", "a", "g", "c", "t", "t", "c", "c", "g", "t", 
    "a", "a", "c", "a", "t", "c", "g", "g", "c", "g", "a", "a", 
    "a", "t", "t", "c", "t", "g", "g", "a", "a", "c", "t", "g", 
    "g", "c", "a", "g", "g", "c", "t", "g", "c", "g", "a", "c", 
    "c", "g", "t", "c", "t", "g", "a", "c", "c", "a", "t", "c", 
    "g", "c", "a", "c", "c", "g", "g", "c", "a", "c", "t", "g", 
    "c", "t", "g", "a", "a", "a", "g", "a", "g", "c", "t", "g", 
    "g", "c", "g", "g", "a", "g", "a", "g", "c", "g", "a", "a", 
    "g", "g", "g", "g", "c", "t", "a", "t", "c", "g", "a", "a", 
    "c", "g", "t", "a", "a", "a", "c", "t", "g", "t", "c", "t", 
    "t", "a", "c", "a", "c", "c", "g", "g", "c", "g", "a", "a", 
    "g", "t", "g", "a", "a", "a", "g", "c", "g", "c", "g", "t", 
    "c", "c", "g", "g", "c", "g", "c", "g", "t", "a", "t", "c", 
    "a", "c", "t", "g", "a", "g", "t", "c", "c", "g", "a", "g", 
    "t", "t", "c", "c", "t", "g", "t", "g", "g", "c", "a", "g", 
    "c", "a", "c", "a", "a", "c", "c", "a", "g", "g", "a", "t", 
    "c", "c", "a", "a", "t", "g", "g", "c", "a", "g", "t", "a", 
    "g", "a", "t", "a", "a", "a", "c", "t", "g", "g", "c", "g", 
    "g", "a", "a", "g", "g", "t", "a", "t", "c", "c", "g", "t", 
    "a", "a", "g", "t", "t", "t", "g", "c", "t", "a", "t", "t", 
    "g", "a", "c", "c", "a", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
    "c", "t", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "g", 
    "a", "t", "c", "g", "g", "c", "g", "a", "t", "c", "t", "g", 
    "c", "t", "g", "t", "a", "a", "t", "c", "a", "t", "t", "c", 
    "t", "t", "a", "g", "c", "g", "t", "g", "a", "c", "c", "g", 
    "g", "g", "a", "a", "g", "t", "c", "g", "g", "t", "c", "a", 
    "c", "g", "c", "t", "a", "c", "c", "t", "c", "t", "t", "c", 
    "t", "g", "a", "a", "g", "c", "c", "t", "g", "t", "c", "t", 
    "g", "t", "c", "a", "c", "t", "c", "c", "c", "t", "t", "c", 
    "g", "c", "a", "g", "t", "g", "t", "a", "t", "c", "a", "t", 
    "t", "c", "t", "g", "t", "t", "t", "a", "a", "c", "g", "a", 
    "g", "a", "c", "t", "g", "t", "t", "t", "a", "a", "a", "c", 
    "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "c", "t", "t", "g", 
    "a", "t", "g", "a", "a", "t", "a", "c", "t", "t", "t", "a", 
    "c", "g", "t", "a", "t", "t", "g", "g", "c", "t", "t", "a", 
    "g", "t", "t", "t", "c", "c", "a", "t", "c", "t", "c", "t", 
    "g", "a", "t", "c", "g", "c", "g", "c", "a", "t", "c", "c", 
    "a", "g"), c("c", "t", "g", "a", "t", "g", "a", "a", "a", 
    "g", "a", "c", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "a", "t", "t", "g", 
    "g", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "g", "t", "g", "t", "g", 
    "t", "c", "g", "c", "a", "t", "t", "t", "g", "c", "t", "t", 
    "t", "c", "c", "a", "g", "c", "c", "a", "a", "c", "t", "g", 
    "a", "c", "c", "c", "g", "c", "a", "t", "t", "t", "t", "a", 
    "c", "g", "c", "a", "c", "c", "c", "a", "c", "g", "c", "a", 
    "g", "c", "a", "a", "t", "g", "a", "g", "c", "g", "t", "a", 
    "c", "t", "t", "g", "g", "g", "c", "a", "t", "g", "g", "t", 
    "t", "t", "g", "c", "t", "g", "c", "g", "c", "g", "g", "c", 
    "g", "c", "g", "g", "g", "g", "c", "t", "g", "g", "g", "a", 
    "g", "g", "c", "c", "c", "t", "g", "t", "a", "g", "g", "t", 
    "g", "c", "g", "g", "c", "a", "c", "t", "a", "a", "a", "t", 
    "g", "g", "g", "g", "t", "t", "a", "a", "a", "g", "c", "g", 
    "g", "t", "c", "a", "g", "c", "g", "g", "c", "a", "g", "c", 
    "g", "c", "c", "t", "a", "t", "c", "g", "c", "g", "t", "g", 
    "a", "c", "g", "a", "t", "t", "c", "c", "a", "g", "c", "c", 
    "g", "t", "a", "c", "t", "g", "c", "a", "a", "a", "t", "c", 
    "g", "c", "c", "t", "g", "c", "c", "t", "g", "c", "g", "c", 
    "c", "g", "g", "a", "t", "g", "g", "t", "t", "a", "g", "c", 
    "g", "c", "c", "a", "c", "t", "c", "a", "g", "g", "t", "c", 
    "t", "g", "a", "t", "a", "c", "c", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", 
    "c", "c", "g", "g", "g", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", 
    "t", "t", "c", "a", "t", "t", "t", "t", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
    "t", "c", "a", "a", "a", "a", "g", "a", "t", "c", "g", "t", 
    "a", "g", "a", "c", "a", "c", "t", "g", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
    "a", "c", "t", "g", "g", "c", "t", "g", "a", "t", "t", "a", 
    "t", "t", "a", "t", "g", "c", "c", "g", "c", "g", "c", "c", 
    "c", "t", "g", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "a", "c", "t", "a", 
    "c", "a", "g", "t", "t", "a", "t", "t", "c", "a", "g", "g", 
    "g", "a", "a", "a", "t", "t", "a", "t", "t", "t", "c", "a", 
    "c", "c", "a", "t", "t", "c", "a", "t", "t", "c", "g", "a", 
    "t", "g", "a", "t", "g", "a", "t", "t", "t", "t", "t", "g", 
    "a", "g", "g", "a", "a", "t", "t", "a", "t", "g", "g", "g", 
    "c", "a", "a", "c", "a", "c", "t", "a", "a", "g", "t", "t", 
    "g", "g", "c", "t", "a", "a", "t", "c", "c", "g", "g", "c", 
    "a", "c", "c", "g", "c", "t", "g", "g", "g", "c", "c", "t", 
    "g", "a", "t", "g", "g", "g", "c", "t", "t"))
```

Comment: I think I got it. I didn't specify what column I'm using in upstream when trying the code you provided. What if I have 4000 rows of sequence?

Comment: 4000 rows? Where? I mean in which data?

Comment: for my upstream data. I have like about 4500 rows :( I just show top 10 rows here.

Comment: It'll still work.  See in `k` I have used a seq upto the length of upstream. But wait, you have to create an empty list first

Comment: See finally edited answer.  I have added `for loops` using baseR only for both earlier and later-edited `upstream` data.  Please have  a look.

Comment: This is working too! Thanks for your help :)